# LL(1) grammar for the untyped lambda-calculus

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, lambda-calculus, parsers

## What I want to do

I am trying to define a LL(1) grammar of the lambda-calculus.

## What I did

Here is the grammar:

1. $Term \to Abs$
2. $Term \to App$
3. $Abs \to \lambda \ id \ . \ Term$
4. $App \to Var \ AppSeq$
5. $AppSeq \to App$
6. $AppSeq \to \epsilon$
7. $Var \to id$
8. $Var \to (\ Term \ )$

Here are the FIRST sets:

- $FIRST(Term) = \{ \lambda, id, ( \}$
- $FIRST(Abs) = \{ \lambda \}$
- $FIRST(App) = \{ id, ( \}$
- $FIRST(AppSeq) = \{ id, (, \epsilon \}$
- $FIRST(Var) = \{ id, ( \}$

Here are FOLLOW sets:

- $FOLLOW(Term) = \{ \$, ) \}$
- $FOLLOW(Abs) = \{ \$, ) \}$
- $FOLLOW(App) = \{ \$, ) \}$
- $FOLLOW(AppSeq) = \{ \$, ) \}$
- $FOLLOW(Var) = \{ \$, (, id \}$

The dragon book give the following definition:

> A grammar G is LL(1) if and only if whenever A → α | β are two
>   distinct productions of G, the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. FIRST(α) and FIRST(β) are disjoint sets
> 2. if ε is in FIRST(β), then FIRST(α)  and FOLLOW(A) are disjoint sets
> 3. likewise if ε is in FIRST(α)

## Question

1. Are my FIRST and FOLLOW sets correct?
2. If no, how can I make it LL(1)?

Comment: Why the so complicated initial grammar?  Isn't $T \rightarrow id\; | \; (T\; T)\; | \; \lambda id.T$ sufficient?

Comment: I also started with something as simple, but it became complex when I tried to remove the need for parentheses for every application (i.e. encoding the rule of left-associativity).

Comment: Closer after your edit, but I think $\mathrm{App} \rightarrow \mathrm{App}\; \mathrm{Var}\; |\; \mathrm{Var}$.  Yours is right associative rather than left.

Comment: @WanderingLogic: It has to be right associative for an LL grammar. (One reason not to use LL grammars, perhaps)

Comment: Is `T` the same as `Term`?

Comment: @rici, the left _recursion_ has to be [eliminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion), but that doesn't mean that we don't want the application operator to be left _associative_.

Comment: @WanderingLogic: Yes. That generally means fixing the parse tree after the parse. (Or, in a recursive descent parser, implement the recursion with a loop.) If you follow the wikipedia link you provided, you'll see that the algorithm for removing left recursion involves turning it into right recursion and altering the associativity (and hence the semantics) of the parse.

Comment: @rici Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: @authchir: In that case, the sets look right to me. What is your doubt?

Comment: @rici The problem was building the $FOLLOW$ sets. I basically guessed $FOLLOW(App)$ and $FOLLOW(AppSeq)$ since they are mutually recursive and the rules for building FOLLOW in the Dragon book do not cover this case (or I did not found it).

Comment: @authclir: The algorithm given in the dragon book starts with the words "apply the following rules *until nothing can be added to any FOLLOW set*", which covers the case of recursive (including mutually recursive) productions.

Comment: Why you need `AppSeq` if `App` is not left recursive?